# Possible to simplify this conditional statement?

Tags: java, logic, conditional-statements

Is it possible to simplify the following statement using && or ||, or even & or | or ^?

```
int result = A ? (B ? 1 : -1) : (B ? -1 : 1);
```

I believe I could assign a temporary variable like so:

```
boolean C = B ? A : !A; // Also: is it correct that this can be simplified to !(A ^ B)?
```

And then do:

```
int result = C ? 1 : -1;
```

But I'm curious if it's possible without a temporary variable.

Comment: Readability first. First one seems better in that respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have answer already.

```
int result = !(A ^ B) ? 1:-1
```

Comment: With Boolean expressions, `!=` is equivalent to `^`. If you used that here, you'd see an easier condition: `!(A ^ B)` is the same as `A == B`.